# Hot reload was rejected: Const class cannot become non-const

Tags: flutter

> I want to remove debug banner and top bar with battery level and wifi
> icons. but it displays an error. where should I correct my code? here
> I have included my main. dart and home. dart.
>
> error>> Hot reload was rejected: Const class cannot become non-const:
> Library:'package:groceries_app/main.dart' Class: MyApp. Try performing
> a hot restart instead.

[image]

> main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:groceries_app/home.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Groceries App',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

> home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();}

class _HomePageState extends State <HomePage>{
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Home Page"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried hot restarting (green arrow) or quitting and re-run the app on the emulator es the error message suggested?

Comment: yes now it works thank you

Comment: Just restart...

Answer (score 18):

Just stop running the app. Then run afresh.

It means you changed a class constructor from being const to not, or vice-versa. Hot reloading will not understand it. Stop execution of the app and run again

Answer (score 0):

If the apps has already been running, the main class has been registered. So, if this class has been changed as const or not const from one to another, it is showing this problem.

In this case, we need to restart it to make it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just hot restart the app. The problem will get solved. It is due to the constructor change from 'const' to 'non-const'.